# Sum of cubes of first n fibonacci numbers

Tags: sequences-and-series, fibonacci-numbers

Let $\{f_k\}$ be the sequence of fibonacci numbers. It is well-known that $\sum_{k=1}^n f_k=f_{n+2}-1$ and $\sum_{k=1}^n f_k^2=f_n f_{n+1}$ . Is there a formula for $\sum_{k=1}^n f_k^3$ ?

Answer (score 12):

$$F_n=\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}(\phi^n-(-\phi)^{-n})\\
\sum_{k=1}^n F_k^3=\frac{1}{5\sqrt{5}}\sum_{k=1}^n(\phi^{3k}-3(-\phi)^k+3\phi^{-k}-(-\phi)^{-3k})$$
and then use Geometric Series

Comment: It should be $F_n=\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}(\phi^n-(-\phi)^{-n})$.

Answer (score 11):

Any time you have a question like this, you should start by computing the first few terms of the sequence and then checking with the OEIS.  In this case, the cubes of $1,1,2,3,5$ are $1,1,8,27,125$, leading to $1,2,10,37,162$, which is [A005968](http://oeis.org/A005968).  An answer to the question can be found there.

Comment: The answer to the question should *also* be found right here, or else this is a link-only answer.

Comment: @ChrisHayes, in this case I disagree.  I gave quite a bit more than a link.  At the same time, I was disinclined to give an utterly complete answer because the OP hadn't shown his or her own attempt to solve the problem or indicated where he/she was stuck.  Also, if the OEIS disappears from online, then we're all sunk anyway ;-)

Answer (score 4):

We have the identity
$$
\sum_{k=1}^n f_k^3=\frac{f_{3n+4}+6(-1)^nf_{n-1}+5}{10},
$$
for all $n\ge 0$. For details see [Recounting the Sums of Cubes of Fibonacci Numbers](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/242771137_Recounting_the_Sums_of_Cubes_of_Fibonacci).

Comment: (+1) Why does this not have more upvotes? It’s the only answer that gives a nice solution in terms of fibonacci numbers.

Answer (score 2):

You could try playing around with a couple of Cassini's identities (as recurrence relations here):

\begin{eqnarray}
F_{3n+1} &=& F_{n+1}^3 + 3 F_{n+1}F_n^2 - F_n^3 \\
F_{3n+2} &=& F_{n+1}^3 + 3 F_{n+1}^2F_n + F_n^3 \\
\end{eqnarray}