# Relation between cubes of Fibonacci numbers and even Fibonacci numbers

Tags: fibonacci-numbers

While recently revisiting an old [Project Euler](https://projecteuler.net/problem=2) problem, which states:

> Each new term in the Fibonacci sequence is generated by adding the previous two terms. By starting with 1 and 2, the first 10 terms will be:
>
> 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89, ...
>
> By considering the terms in the Fibonacci sequence whose values do not exceed four million, find the sum of the even-valued terms.

I noticed the following.

Let $F_n = 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, \ldots$ as defined in the problem. Then, assuming zero indexing, for all $n \ge 2$,

$$F_n^3 + F_{n-1}^3 - F_{n-2}^3 = F_{3(n-1)}.$$

This evidently holds for the first few $n$:

$$F_2^3 + F_1^3 - F_0^3 = 27 + 8 - 1 = 34 = F_7$$
$$F_3^3 + F_2^3 - F_1^3 = 125 + 27 - 8 = 144 = F_{10}$$

and so forth.

I have tried using [Cassini's Identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cassini_and_Catalan_identities) and its generalizations to prove this, but to no avail.

I've also found [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1053050/31475), but cannot find the derivation of this solution, and cannot quite reconcile it with my observation.

My question: does my observation hold true, and if so, how can I go about proving this. What am I missing?

Comment: For the original problem, you maya also note that the even valued fibos obey $x_{n+1}=4x_n+x_{n-1}$

Comment: shouldn't it be $F_n^3 + F_{n-1}^3 - F_{n-2}^3 = F_{3(n-1)}$ which is valid for whichever $n$, even negative ?

Comment: yes, i made a typo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have Binet's formula,
$$ F_n=\frac{\phi^n-\psi^n}{\sqrt 5}$$
where $\phi=\frac{1+\sqrt 5}2$ and $\psi=\frac{1-\sqrt 5}2$ are the two roots of $X^2-X-1$.
You can plug this into your conjectured equality, expand and simplify (using in particular that $\phi+\psi=1$, $\phi-\psi=\sqrt 5$, $\phi\psi=-1$), and check.

Comment: of course, i should have seen this